Spring Security 6 AuthenticationManager for custom login on post request is getting 401 unauthorized responses but get request is working fine
I am learning to implement spring security with custom login, implementing AuthenticationManager but on post request getting 401 response but if I change to get request then working fine.
My Security configuration class:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration config) throws Exception {
        return config.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

My Login Controller:
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    LoginService loginService;

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String login(@RequestBody User user){
                System.out.println(user); //This also not coming in console log
        return loginService.verify(user);

    }

}

I want on post request application should at least print provided detail in console log
